# How to split a two-dimensional JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON array of arrays like this:

```
[["abcd@gmail.com","joe"], ["xyz@gmail.com","brain"], ["hhh@gmail.com","bob"]]
```

How can I get the values separately?

```
<div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
    {{ email should be here }} : {{ name here }}
</div>
```

I need the email and name separately, but it's not displaying anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/1c12r4hr/2/
Its one possible way of doing that

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var persons = [["abcd@gmail.com","joe"],["xyz@gmail.com","brain"],["hhh@gmail.com","bob"]];

    var newPersons = [];
    for(var i=0; i< persons.length; i++){
        var tempObj = {};
        tempObj.email = persons[i][0];
         tempObj.name = persons[i][1];
        newPersons.push(tempObj);
    }
console.log(newPersons)
    $scope.persons = newPersons;

}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
        {{person.email}} {{person.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Controller:**

```
$scope.data = [["abcd@gmail.com","joe"],["xyz@gmail.com","brain"],["hhh@gmail.com","bob"]];
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper" ng-repeat="each in data">
  {{ each[0] }} : {{ each[1] }}
</div>
```